# Определение и реализация

Tags: c++

У методов в классе есть приставки virtual и тп, а так же после метода const, override, final, & и тп.

Как они классифицируются, называются (до и после)? Есть предположение что все что после пишется в реализации, а не только в определении, метода, а до - нет, верно ли это?

На en.cppreference.com не нашел такого разделения, ткните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Abyx , обе группы входят в сигнатуру? Почему некоторые находятся до, а другие после? Их никак не различают?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть сигнатуры (типы) функций, и есть ключевые слова (спецификаторы), которые добавляются к объявлению функции-члена класса.

Сигнатуры функций должны повторяться в объявлении функции, и в ее определении.
Ключевые слова static, virtual, override, final, `= 0` - используются только при объявлении функции, в теле класса.

Это можно проиллюстрировать так:

```
using F = void(); // сигнатура функции (в т.ч. члена класса)
using M1 = void() const; // сигнатура, может быть только у членов класса
using M2 = void() const &; 

F f; // объявление функции f с сигнатурой F
void f() {} // определение функции f

struct X {
  F f1; // объявление функции-члена класса f1 с сигнатурой F
  static F f2; // объявление статической функции-члена класса
  virtual F f3; // объявление виртуальной функции-члена класса
  virtual F f4 = 0; // объявление чисто-виртуальной функции-члена класса
  virtual M1 m1 = 0;
  virtual M2 m2 = 0;
};

void X::f1() {} // Определения функций f1, f2, f3
void X::f2() {}
void X::f3() {}

struct Y : X {
  F f4 override; // переопределения виртуальных функций f4, m1, m2
  virtual M1 m1;
  M2 m2 final;
};

void Y::f4 {} // Определения функций f4, m1, m2
void Y::m1 const {}
void Y::m2 const & {}
```

То, с какой стороны находятся ключевые слова static, virtual, override, final, `= 0` - определяется синтаксисом С++.

Comment: вопрос - можно ли писать кл. слово `virtual` в **определении** функции? 2) Я лично вижу некоторую противоречивость синтаксиса в том, что virtual/static должны быть слева, а override/final - справа. ИМХО `final virtual void f();` выглядело бы лучше, чем `virtual void f() final;`

Comment: то что логики нет - ясно, я об этом и пишу. Хотелось бы, чтобы она была все же.

Comment: Добавил бы, что `cv-qualifier` (квалификатор собсвенно метода) `const` **должен** писаться и в объявлении и в определении, т.к. меняет сигнатуру(?).

Comment: `= 0` это спецификатор, а не ключевое слово. `override` и `final` тоже не являются ключевыми словами. `static` может относиться так же и к свободным функциям, не членам. В этом случае можно добавлять `static` при определении, если при объявлении тоже было указано.

Answer (score 4):

Всё что входит в сигнатуру функции должно повторяться в ее объявлениях/определениях – (c) Abyx

```
const SomeType method1();
SomeType method2() const;
```

- это разные методы (функции) с разными сигнатурами.
  Первая возвращает константный объект типа `SomeType`, вторая возвращает обычный (неконстантный) объект того же типа, но не имеет права модифицировать объект, от имени которого вызывается.

Законченный пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() : x(0) {}
    const int m1() { x = 1; return x; } // warning: type qualifiers ignored
                                        // on function return type
    int const m11() { x = 1; return x; } // absolutely same as m1
    int m2() const { return x; } // but will not compile if you add x = 1;
    const A m3() { return A(); }
    A m4() const { return A(); }
    const A m5() { x = 1; return A(); } // ok
    A m6() const { x = 1; return A(); } // error
private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << a.m3().m1() << endl; // error: passing const A as 'this' argument of
                                 // 'const A::m1()' discards qualifiers
    cout << a.m3().m2() << endl; // but this works
    cout << a.m4().m1() << endl; // and this works too
    return 0;
}
```

Вообще, **спецификаторы** `virtual`, `override`, `final` - относятся только непосредственно к самой функции, в отличие от **квалификатора** `const`, который может относится как к функции (если находится справа от имени функции-метода), так и к возвращаемому значению (слева от имени функции). Нужно помнить, что `const` всегда относится к тому, что непосредственно слева от него, за исключением случая, когда `const` - самое первое слова и тогда относится к тому, что непосредственно справа:

```
int const * a // pointer to const int, same as const int * a
int * const b // const pointer to int
```

PS Объяснить, почему спецификатор `virtual` должен быть слева, а `final` - справа - я не могу.

Для обычных функций (НЕ методов):

```
int q() const { return 1; } // error: non-member function cannot have cv-qualifier
int & f() { int *a = new int; *a = 0; return *a; }
const int &  g() { int *a = new int; *a = 0; return *a; }

    cout << f() << endl; // ok 0
    cout << g() << endl; // ok 0
    cout << ++f() << endl; // ok 1
    cout << ++g() << endl; // error: increment of read only location g()
```

Comment: «Объяснить, почему спецификатор `virtual` должен быть слева, а `final `- справа - я не могу» — потому что `virtual` это ключевое слова, а `final` это контексто-зависимый идентификатор. `final` не может быть в начале потому, что пользователь может создать тип с именем `final`